# how to write junit for this code service layer in springboot

Tags: java, junit5

i am new in junit

I want to test this method with junit5 when i try to test this custom exception like this:

```
 CustomExceptionMessage exception = assertThrows(CustomExceptionMessage.class,() -> when(accountJpaRepository.existsByAccountName(accountModel.getAccountName())).thenReturn(true)
        );
    assertEquals(Constant.ACCOUNT_EXIST,exception.getMessage());
```

how can we test this method properly?

```
//here is service layer method

    @Override
    public AccountModel addAccount(final AccountModel accountModel) {
   
    String firstFourChars = "";
    if (accountModel.getCompanyName().length() > 4) {
        firstFourChars = accountModel.getCompanyName().substring(0, 4);
    } else {
        firstFourChars = accountModel.getCompanyName();
    }
    String lastFiveDigits = "";
    if (accountModel.getPhone().length() > 5) {
        lastFiveDigits = accountModel.getPhone().substring(0, 5);
    } else {
        lastFiveDigits = accountModel.getPhone();
    }
    String acountName = firstFourChars.concat(lastFiveDigits);
    accountModel.setAccountName(acountName);
    if (accountJpaRepository.existsByAccountName(accountModel.getAccountName())) {
        throw new CustomExceptionMessage(Constant.ACCOUNT_EXIST);
    }
    if (accountJpaRepository.existsByEmail(accountModel.getEmail())) {
        throw new CustomExceptionMessage(Constant.EMAIL_EXIST);
    }
    return accountRepository.addAccount(accountModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you were almost there :)
This would be my take on this problem:

```
@Test
void test() {

    var accountModel = new AccountModel(...);
    var accountJpaRepository = mock(AccountJpaRepository.class);
    when(accountJpaRepository.existsByAccountName(accountModel.getAccountName())).thenReturn(true);

    var cut = new YourUnnamedService(accountJpaRepository)

    var exception = assertThrows(CustomExceptionMessage.class, () ->
            cut.addAccount(accountModel);
    );

    assertEquals(Constant.ACCOUNT_EXIST,exception.getMessage());
}
```

The first thing to do is to create an `AccountModel`. This will be used for the mocking of the `AccountJpaRepository` and as the parameter for your `addAccount` Method.
The next two lines mock the behavior of your `AccountJpaRepository`. This is done to isolate your `YourUnnamedService` from its dependencies.
After this preparation, you instantiate `YourUnnamedService` and pass all its dependencies into its constructor.
Inside JUnits `assertThrows` you just have to call the method you want to test, and make your assertions afterward.

Answer (score 0):

```
   this is how i run the code , that actualy work for me.
    private AccountModel getAccountModelObject() {
    AccountModel accountModel = new AccountModel();
    accountModel .setAccountId((long) 1);
    accountModel .setAccountOwner("Dinesh Singh");
    accountModel .setAccountName("Dinesh");
    return accountModel ;
    }

     @Test
    void testAddAccountMethodWithAccountExistException() {
    AccountModel getAccountModel = getAccountModelObject();
    when(accountJpaRepository.existsByAccountName(
     getAccountModel.getAccountName())).thenReturn(true);
    CustomExceptionMessage exception = 
     assertThrows(CustomExceptionMessage.class,
            () -> accountServiceImpl.addAccount(getAccountModel));
    assertEquals(Constant.ACCOUNT_EXIST, exception.getMessage());
  }
```

firstly we need to provide mock value for AccountModel class , then true that condition that throw exception ,now for check exception we use asssertThrows ,in this we passed the own custom exception class as a first parameter that we use in our service class code ,then in second parameter as a lambda expression we call service class method .
then we check that returned exception message is equal to our exception message ,if it equal then code work fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).